# Complex math formula Python

Tags: python, math, cluster-analysis, equation

[image: Maths Formula]I have been trying to program a math formula in python. The code is running but I have strong belief that the code is not reflecting the actual math formulas,but I am so lost I don't know where I could have gone wrong. Below is my code and I have attached the actual maths formula. Please check if the python code matches the math formula -if not, assist on where I am going wrong. I am honestly so lost.

```
## Inter cluster distance
inter = 0 
for i in range(centr.shape[1]-1):
  for j in range(i+1,centr.shape[1]):
    for l in range(centr.shape[0]):
      inter = inter + (centr[l][i]-centr[l][j])**2    
print('Intercluster distance: '+ str(inter))
## Intra cluster cluster
intra = 0
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
  for j in range(centr.shape[0]):[enter image description here][2]
    intra = intra + (data[i][j] - centr[j][Cc[i]-1])**2
print('Intracluster distance: '+ str(intra))
```

[Math equation intra-cluster distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufIaI.png)
[Mth equation inter-cluster distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dih6.png)

[My code in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dih6.png)

[image: Code that works][image: Code that is not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe how the `range` constructor works:

```py
>>> list(range(3))
[0, 1, 2]

>>> list(range(1, 3))
[1, 2]
```

So the default start value is 0, and the stop value is never included. You thus need slightly different start and stop values.

Also, the indices for the matrix elements `z` in your code are probably all off by 1 unit compared to the formula you give, because Python indexing works similarly to `range`, starting at 0, whereas in the formula they apparently start at 1.

So e.g. for the inter-cluster distance, we should have this code:

```py
## Inter cluster distance
inter = 0 
for i in range(1, centr.shape[1]):
    for j in range(i+1, centr.shape[1] + 1):
        for l in range(1, 3 + 1):
            inter = inter + (centr[l - 1][i - 1] - centr[l - 1][j - 1])**2    
print('Intercluster distance: '+ str(inter))
```

Or you could make the indices `i, j, l` all one unit smaller and index the `z` values accordingly, which should yield the same result:

```py
## Inter cluster distance
inter = 0 
for i in range(centr.shape[1] - 1):
    for j in range(i, centr.shape[1]):
        for l in range(3):
            inter = inter + (centr[l][i] - centr[l][j])**2    
print('Intercluster distance: '+ str(inter))
```

Comment: Hi Arne, Thank you for explaining how the range works. It is clear now. I have applied the formula as demonstrated. I confirm that centr.shape is (15,5) where 5 represent number of clusters (K). But I am getting an error: ----> 6             inter = inter + (centr[l][i]-centr[l][j])**2. IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Kate. I have edited my answer in light of your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much Arne, the code is working and it is giving better results. I still need to look at it closely to fully grasp the concept- how you explained the range was very helpful. And with this clarity, I hope I can solve the Intra-cluster formula. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks @Kate, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Hi @Arne, I have a quick question. I have applied the formula as you adviced and its working. It is actually working where centr is a multidimensional array  eg centr.shape = (15,5) where 15 is the number of columns/features and 5 is K. But I experience a problem when centr.shape is (2,5). I get an error "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2".  Please can you help me on how I can fix this. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Kate, that could be the same issue as above, i.e. the fact that indexing starts at 0. So if `centr.shape[0]` is 2, the index can be 0 or 1, but not 2. I would need to see the code that causes the error to be sure though.

Comment: Hi @Arne, I have implemented the code as you explained- but I think I am experiencing an indexing problem when the centre shape changes. Please see the 3 images attached- One is the math formula I am trying to implement. One is the code where the code works and another one it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Kate, so the problem arises with `l = 2` in that case, because your matrix is too small. You could change the code to `for l in range(2):` to make it work, but note that this would no longer correspond to the formula you give. That formula simply requires the matrix to have size 3 in that dimension.

Comment: Thank you so much @Arne. The explanation makes it clear. I will see what I can do.